# I want to hide or show rows based on a value placed in a previous cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an interactive worksheet where I have people input yes or no answers. I have a grouping of questions that if someone answers no in the first one, the next two are not required. How do I create a function that will hide the rows once a no is given?

I am relatively new to advanced functionality in Excel so I have mostly been looking at different forms of code that my colleagues have provided.

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("B6") = "no"
    Rows("7:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a `Worksheet_Change()` event - try placing this in the corresponding Sheet module under Microsoft Excel Objects:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then
        If Target.Value = "no" Then
            Rows("7:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Rows("7:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```